# How can I create a semi-random grid of numbers such that each number appears once, AND most importantly is not too close to its precedding number?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, random, grid

Lets say I have a grid (10x10) and I want to fill it with the number sequence 0 - 99. Here are some conditions:

1. Each number in the sequence should appear only once in the grid.
2. The placement of each number (from the sequence) should be random (x,y co-ordinates).
3. Subsequent numbers from the sequence (e.g. 5 and 6) cannot appear in the grid adjacent (or within a radius) of each other.

I can handle conditions 1 and 2 no problem. Condition 3 is harder (for me). I have used brute-force to fill the grid, but this has a couple of problems. Firstly, it is slow when the grid is biggish (100x100). Secondly (and most importantly), brute-force does not guarantee a solution (i.g. the final two numbers in the sequence will be adjacent each other and therefore not allowed -> no solution).

If someone can help me with a suitable algorithm (or even some maths/logic resources) that will be helpful. If you can provide a solution, ideally condition 3 should be definable (i.e. the user/coder determines the radius for which adjacent numbers cannot appear). Finally, there is no issue of wrap-around (i.e. if the number 5 in the last column of a row, then 6 can appear in the first column of the next row).

Lots of words, but I think this is a pretty cool problem with a real-world need ('random' photo-excitation of neurons).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a recursive back-tracking algorithm, which puts a random valid number in each cell. If there is no valid cell, it back-tracks and picks another number for a previous cell. Using enumerator-methods, you can easily build a back-tracking system.

```
class Generator
{
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Radius { get; private set; }

    private List<int> _numbers;
    private bool[] _picked;
    private int[] _grid;
    private Random _rnd;

    public Generator(int width, int height, int radius)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Radius = radius;

        _rnd = new Random();
        _numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,Width*Height).OrderBy(_ => _rnd.Next()).ToList();
        _picked = _numbers.Select(n => false).ToArray();
        _grid = new int[width*height];
    }

    public int[] Generate()
    {
        return Generate(0)
            .Select(a => a.ToArray()) // copy
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private IEnumerable<int[]> Generate(int index)
    {
        if (index >= Width * Height)
        {
            yield return _grid;
            yield break;
        }

        int xmid = index%Width;
        int xlow = Math.Max(0, xmid - Radius);
        int xhigh = Math.Min(xmid + Radius, Width - 1);
        int ymid = index/Width;
        int ylow = Math.Max(0, ymid - Radius);
        int yhigh = ymid;

        var validNumbers = _numbers
            .Where(n =>
                !_picked[n] &&
                Enumerable.Range(xlow, xhigh - xlow + 1).All(x =>
                    Enumerable.Range(ylow, yhigh-ylow+1).All(y =>
                        y*Width + x >= index // Not generated yet
                        || Math.Abs(x - xmid) + Math.Abs(y - ymid) > Radius // Outside radius
                        || Math.Abs(_grid[y*Width+x] - n) > 1 // Out of range
                    )
                )
            )
            .ToList();

        foreach (var n in validNumbers)
        {
            _grid[index] = n;
            _picked[n] = true;
            foreach (var sol in Generate(index + 1))
            {
                yield return sol;
            }
            _picked[n] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**10x10 grid, with radius 4 generated in 50 ms:**

```
74   6  72   1  82  64  41  66  96  17 
61  24  12  93  35  86  52  19  47  10 
42  48  69  45  79  88  31  43  28  36 
15  38   4  40  54  33  13   7  90  68 
34  67  62  83  99  59  50  22  73  77 
44  18   0   8  20  81  26  37  98  87 
29  71  58  75  14  65  55  85  57  80 
84  32  91  25   5  78  95   9   2  53 
60  23  11  63  49  39  70  89  27  46 
97  16   3  30  56  92  76  51  21  94
```

Often it is quick, and completes in under a second. Sometimes it makes a bad choice at the beginning, and have to back-track a lot.

Comment: Here is some crude performance analysis [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ali2OQm5JfHsdEFVSDhIcFFrQWE4ZG5rbDgyZnhnOXc&usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks Markus for your answer - it is a elegant solution. I do find it fails (no exception thrown) when I try to create a grid that is too big (area > ~2500). Also, I have wrapped the call to Generator.Generate in a 'Task with a CancellationToken to allow the Generate method to timeout safely (without freezing).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea:

For an `NxN` grid, generate a list of numbers `0..NxN-1`, then shuffle it (Fisher-Yates or whatever).

Then, fill out the grid: for each cell, pick the first element in the shuffled list that will fit according to your rules and the current state of the grid. Remove each element from the shuffled list as it is moved to the grid.

If you fail to fill a grid cell because there are no valid numbers left in the shuffled list, search through the filled grid cells until you find a cell where the number *there* is valid *here*, and one of the numbers left in the shuffled list is also valid *there*. Then move *there* to *here* and move the valid number from the list *there*.

I'm not sure whether it's possible that you would not find such a number unless your radius was set too high for any solution to exist. Exercise for the reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the algorithm I used for generating a star field for a game.  I had a galaxy of a given dimension laid out on a cartesian plane and a desired number of stars.  The stars could not occupy the same place or be with in n units of one another.  I snicked some stuff out, but this should help.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < u.StarCount; i++)
        {
            bool badStar = true;  //Assume failure
            do
            {
                //Create a star, get a random location, and where the rarity of its spectral type
                StellarBody sb = new StellarBody();
                sb.PositionX = r.Next(0, u.width);
                sb.PositionY = r.Next(0, u.height);
                int randomAbundance = r.Next(maxAbundance);

                //Test the location against previous stars added, disallow positions where the centers are within 8 units of one another
                if (!u.StellarBodies.Any(p => Math.Abs(p.PositionX.Value - sb.PositionX.Value) < minGap && Math.Abs(p.PositionY.Value - sb.PositionY.Value) < minGap))
                {
                    //Get the spectral types based on the abundance value of the spectral types compared to the random abundance number
                    List<Models.StellarClass> abundanceTypes = starTypes.FindAll(f => f.Abundance == starTypes.Where(p => p.Abundance > randomAbundance).Min(m => m.Abundance));

                    try
                    {
                        int index = r.Next(0, abundanceTypes.Count());
                        sb.StellarClassID = abundanceTypes[index].StellarClassID;                            
                        sb.CatalogDesignation = index.ToString() + u.StellarBodies.Count.ToString()
                                                + abundanceTypes[index].Code + "-" + CoordinateMath.GetMortonNumber((int)sb.PositionX, (int)sb.PositionY).ToString();

                        minOrbit = abundanceTypes[index].MinOrbitZone;
                        maxOrbit = abundanceTypes[index].MaxOrbitZone;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        sb.StellarClassID = starTypes.First(p => p.Code.Equals("Dork", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).StellarClassID;
                    }


                    u.StellarBodies.Add(sb);
                    badStar = false;
                }
            } while (badStar);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fill the grid fast (trying to avoid clumping, but not trying too hard). When the grid is filled I would find clumping numbers and move them around. No backtracking involved. This approach should be very effective for very large grids.

Pseudocode of first phase:

```
int N = 100;
int minDistance = 10;
int maxCollisionCount = 5;
int saturationThreshold = N * N * 0.85;

grid[0,0] = 1;
int oldX = 0, oldY = 0;
int newX, newY;

for (i = 2; i <= N * N; i++)
{
    bool foundNewCell = false;

    for (collisionCount = 0; collisionCount < maxCollisionCount; collisionCount++)
    {
        newX = rnd(0, N - minDistance);
        if (newX >= oldX - minDistance / 2)
            newX += minDistance;

        newY = rnd(0, N - minDistance);
        if (newY >= oldY - minDistance / 2)
            newY += minDistance;

        if (grid[newX, newY] == 0)
        {
            grid[oldX = newX, oldY = newY] = i;
            foundNewCell = true;
            break;
        }

        if (i > saturationThreshold)
            break;
    }

    if (foundNewCell)
        continue;

    // Find newX and newY by some other way, even if there would be clumping.
    // For instance use already randomed newX and newY and circle around until
    // you find an empty cell
    ...

    grid[oldX = newX, oldY = newY] = i;
}
```